# how to pass airflow ts_nodash in a json template

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-platform, airflow, airflow-api

I need to have an API call from the Ariflow dag.

Below is the sample json_string I use in code:

```
    def api_call_func(**context):
        source_file_name = context["dag_run"].conf["source_file_names"]
    json_data = { "filenames":[
                 {"FileName":[f'Source_credit_{{{{ ts_nodash }}}}']}
                  ]
                }

        json_string = json.dumps(json_data, 
                        skipkeys = True, 
                        allow_nan = True)
        requests.post(url = API_URL, data = json_string)

    api_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='api_task',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=api_call_func,
    dag=dag,
    )
```

but it is resulting in the below response:

```
<filenames>
         <FileName>f'Source_credit_{{ ts_nodash }}</FileName>
</filenames>
```

below is the response desired with the currentDateTime:

```
<filenames>
         <FileName>f'Source_credit_20210408010223</FileName> 
</filenames>
```

How to pass the ts_nodash macros in json?
or how to pass the dag's execution datetime in json?

Comment: How do you exactly use `json_str`? Templates are processed only if the string containing them is passed as an argument to a templated parameter of an operator. E.g., `op_args` parameter of the `PythonOperator`.

Comment: As was mentioned Airflow defines which parameter can be templated or not and it strongly depends on the particular operator implementation. Can you share some code lines to us to proper get the point?

Comment: Please find the code lines added. hope it helps @Nick_Kh

Comment: I have added code lines which shows how json_str is used. please help out @SergiyKolesnikov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Templates are processed only if the string containing them is passed as an argument to a templated parameter of an operator. E.g., `op_args` parameter of  `PythonOperator`.

In your case, the value of `ts_nodash` is passed to `api_call_func()` as an argument by the `PythonOperator`. So, you can use the `context` parameter to access it:

```
json_data = {
    "ID": "A001-001",
    "SourceName": sourcefile,
    "filenames": [{"FileName": [f"Source_credit_{context['ts_nodash']}"]}],
}
```

Note, the values for the rest of the [default variables](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/macros-ref.html#default-variables) can be accessed in the same way.

Comment: can I also do - `json_data = {     "ID": "A001-001",     "SourceName": sourcefile,     "filenames": [{"FileName": [f"Source_credit_{ context['execution_date.subtract(seconds=2).strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")'] }"]}], } ` @SergiyKolesnikov

Comment: I don't think so, but you can get `cotext['execution_date']` then convert it to datetime and process it further.

Comment: `{ context["execution_date"].subtract(seconds=2).strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S") }` this one worked. Thanks a lot :) @SergiyKolesnikov